# Sorting timestamps in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

Newbie here in Laravel 4. Say I have a model ("Activity") that has a timestamp column, along with other metadata. When I print it out in HTML, it is arranged from earliest to latest, which won't be ideal.I want to sort it from latest to earliest, because I'm going after an activity log.

Here's the code on the view:

```
@foreach ($activities as $activity)
<tr class="activity">
    <td>{{ $activity->timestamp }}</td>
    <td>{{ $activity->activity }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Here's the controller code, which arranges these stuff:

```
public function getActivity()
{
        return View::make('app.website.activity', array('activities' => Activity::all()));
}
```

Is there anything I can do with Activity::all() to sort it out by time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using the default laravel timestamps you can get the activities in descending order like this:

```
Activity::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

If you have manually added your timestamp column you can get them in descending order like this:

```
Activity::orderBy('timestamp','desc')->get();
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.